# Using Qt(C++) execBatch() insert Oracle, After that, only one character is inserted of “string” in database

Tags: c++, oracle, qt

This is the code in C++:
    QSqlQuery* pQuery = m_pDataBaseWrapper->GetQuery();

```
pQuery->prepare("insert into jiajia_test values (?, ?)");
QVariantList ints;
ints << 1 << 2 << 3 << 4;
pQuery->addBindValue(ints);

QVariantList names;
names << "Harald" << "Boris" << "Trond" << QVariant(QVariant::String);
pQuery->addBindValue(names);

if (!pQuery->execBatch())
    WriteLog("update sucesss");

return true;
```

after insert the database:

[image]

the database config：

[image]

Comment: Have you tried querying the database from your application? What do you get? something like `QSqlQuery q; q.exec("SELECT * FROM jiajia_test"); while(q.next()) qDebug() << q.value(0).toString() << q.value(1).toString();`. Do you still get one letter for each column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the problem，the question is in qsqlocid4.dll, I use the oci prj of qt,get a  new dll， this problem solves.